# How to handle object on onResponse of retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is my logic for  getting response in retrofit 2.0

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Wallet>>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Response<ArrayList<Wallet>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

      if (response.isSuccess()) {
          // use response data and do some fancy stuff :)
         loading.dismiss();
          ArrayList<Wallet> orders = response.body();
          Utility.displayToast("Wallet size is" + orders.size());

      } else {

      }
  }

});


Data format from rest API is like this:

[
{
  "description": "Cashback",
  "amount": "20.00",
  "type": "1",
  "date": "11/03/2016"
},
{
  "description": "CASH BACK",
  "amount": "12.00",
  "type": "1",
  "date": "05/03/2016"
}
]
```

Now they have changes the API and data is coming like this:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "wallet": [
    {
      "description": "Cashback",
      "amount": "20.00",
      "type": "1",
      "date": "11/03/2016"
    },
    {
      "description": "CASH BACK",
      "amount": "12.00",
      "type": "1",
      "date": "05/03/2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to handle object in ONResponse and parse wallet information in array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the PoJo has to change. E.g.

```
public class NewWallet {
    public boolean error;
    public List<Wallet> wallet;
}
```

and let your interface return `NewWallet` instead of `ArrayList<Wallet>`

Answer (score 1):

If your all apis changed like this only, then better to use templates.

```
public class ResponseDS<T> {
    public boolean error;
    public List<T> data;
}
```

Now you can pass Wallet or any other Object as T for the response with signature. :)