# Retrofit2 Android: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I know this is not the first time someone asking about this problem but with Retrofit2 I can't find the right solution to my problem. I followed a online tutorial and it worked just fine. When I applied same code to my own endpoint i get this exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $` I don't know how to solve this.

Interface:

```
public interface MyApiService {

// Is this right place to add these headers?
@Headers({"application-id: MY-APPLICATION-ID",
        "secret-key: MY-SECRET-KEY",
        "application-type: REST"})
@GET("Music")
Call<List<Music>> getMusicList();



Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(MySettings.REST_END_POINT)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
}
```

Client code:

```
MyApiService service = MyApiService.retrofit.create(MyApiService.class);
Call<List<Music>> call = service.getMusicList();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Music>>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Music>> call, Response<List<Music>> response) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", response.body().
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Music>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", t.toString());
    }
});
```

This code working with this payload:

```
[
{
    "login": "JakeWharton",
    "id": 66577,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/66577?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/JakeWharton",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/JakeWharton/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "contributions": 741
},
{....
```

but not with this one:

```
{
"offset": 0,
"data": [
    {
        "filename": "E743_1458662837071.mp3",
        "created": 1458662854000,
        "publicUrl": "https://api.backendless.com/dbb77803-1ab8-b994-ffd8-65470fa62b00/v1/files/music/E743_1458662837071.mp3",
        "___class": "Music",
        "description": "",
        "likeCount": 0,
        "title": "hej Susanne. ",
        "ownerId": "E743756F-E114-6892-FFE9-BCC8C072E800",
        "updated": null,
        "objectId": "DDD8CB3D-ED66-0D6F-FFA5-B14543ABC800",
        "__meta": "{\"relationRemovalIds\":{},\"selectedProperties\":[\"filename\",\"created\",\"publicUrl\",\"___class\",\"description\",\"likeCount\",\"title\",\"ownerId\",\"updated\",\"objectId\"],\"relatedObjects\":{}}"
    },
    {...
```

My Music class:

```
public class Music {

   private String ownerId;
   private String filename;
   private String title;
   private String description;
   private String publicUrl;
   private int likeCount;

   // Getters & Setters

}
```

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956104/how-to-handle-object-on-onresponse-of-retrofit-2-0/35956131#35956131). You need to return a different class which contains a `List<Music> data`

Comment: It expects an array, you give it an object

Answer (score 158, accepted):

When you say "This code is working with this payload:... but not with this one:..." that's expected and that's how it's suppose to work. In fact the error message tells you that while converting the json to a java object the call expected an array in the json but got an object instead.

This call:

```
@GET("Music")
Call<List<Music>> getMusicList();
```

expects a list of `Music` objects, that's why it works with the json:

```
[
  {
    "login": "JakeWharton",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Because the json itself is an array of your `Music` objects (Retrofit can convert between json arrays to java lists). For the second json you have just an object and not an array (notice the lack of `[...]`). For this you need to create another call with another model that maps to that json. Let's assume you've named the model `MusicList`. Here's how the call could look like:

```
@GET("Music")
Call<MusicList> getMusicList();
```

(Note that you might need to change the method name if you want to keep both the first call and this one).

The `MusicList` model can look something like this:

```
public class MusicList {
  @SerializedName("data")
  private List<Music> musics;
  // ...
}
```

I'm assuming that the `data` array is a list of `Music` objects, but I did notice that the jsons are completely different. You might need to adapt this as well, but I think you get the picture here.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this, I spent the whole day trying to find a solution and thanks to your tip it worked. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Thanks !! worked ,didnot notice this minor issue

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. It's because the payload is an object instead of an array of objects. So I removed List.

Code Example

UserAPI.java

```
public interface UserAPI {
    @GET("login/cellphone")
    Call<LoginResponse> login(@Query("phone") String phone, 
                              @Query("password") String password);
}
```

Call code

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
        .Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(Constant.CLOUD_MUSIC_API_BASE_URL)
        .build();

UserAPI userAPI = retrofit.create(UserAPI.class);

userAPI.login(phone, password).enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
        System.out.println("onResponse");
        System.out.println(response.body().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("onFailure");
        System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
    }
});
```

Comment: A side note: using GET as a method for login has some security issues, you should opt for a POST instead. Plz check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868860/3503855

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In my case the issue was about my return type of this function was wrong I was returning `retrofit2.Call<List<GamesModel>>` this error means that GSON was expecting an array to come back from your server.

I just remove the List and now it's working fine