# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY : Retrofit2 Android

Tags: android, json, runtime-error, retrofit2

I am new in JSON parsing and trying to parse the following JSON:

```
[
 {
"id" : 1,
"title" : {
    "rendered": "a link"
 },
"categories": [ 4,9,11 ],
"links":{
        "featuredmedia":[
        {
          "href": link
        }
           ]
    }
},
...
]
```

My Interface is:

```
public interface MediaAPI {
    @GET("Media")
    Call<LinkList> getDetails();
}
```

My model classes are:

```
public class LinkList {
    private List<Links> links;
    // getter and setter    
}
```

...

```
public class Links {
  private List<Featuredmedia> Featured = new ArrayList<Featuredmedia>();
  // getter and setter 
 }
```

...

```
public class Featuredmedia {
    private String href;
    // getter and setter    
}
```

and Client code is:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    MediaAPI service = retrofit.create(MediaAPI.class);

    Call<LinkList> call = service.getDetails();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LinkList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LinkList> call, Response<LinkList> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){                   
                successToast();
            }
            else {                                      
                failToast();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LinkList> call, Throwable t) {               
            Log.d("Failed", t.getMessage());
            showToast();

        }
    });
```

I only need to get the link inside "featuredmedia" so I only included those in the models. I also got some idea about the error from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177629/retrofit2-android-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2) but the error still there.

Any suggestion how to solve this will be great help.

Comment: Instead of Call<LinkList> getDetails(), try Call<Links> getDetails()

Comment: To better understand JSON, please [read this link](http://www.json.org/), and check these tools: [formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) and [editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) that greatly help (at least me) validate and "read" what the Data is, and what it means... Basically `[...]`are Arrays, and `{...}` are Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Links` model like this .

```
public class Links {
  private List<Featuredmedia> featuredmedia = new ArrayList<Featuredmedia>();
  // getter and setter 
 }
```

And also `LinkList` should be like this .

```
public class LinkList {
    private Links links;
    // getter and setter    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gson will take care of Deserializing the json to your LinksList and expects an object for this to work.

Your model basically expects something like :

```
{
   links: [...]
}
```

Since your Response Json is an array, you want to have a model representing this: any Array or List will do.

So instead of using LinkList, just use e.g. `Call<List<Links>>`