# How to post other parameter with @body in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

My code is:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded

 @POST("/api/userlogin")

 void getUserLogin(@Query("client_id")String  id,@Query("client_secret")String  secret,@Query("username")String  uname, @Body HashMap<String, String> arguments, Callback<LoginResult> cb);
```

This gives error please help..

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: may be it can help you ... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177629/retrofit2-android-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177629/retrofit2-android-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chage in @Body :

```
@Body TypedInput arguments
```

for more:

[How to POST raw whole JSON in the body of a Retrofit request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request)