# Receiving error "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT"

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have this problem and cant seem to find a solution. I have Googled around but to no avail.

The API is returning an array of objects but gson has found an object.

**My Model**

```
public class Message {

private int id;
private String title;
private String details;  }
```

**MessageClient**

```
public interface MessageClient {

@GET("/api/test")
Call<List<Message>> getMessages();}
```

**Implementation**

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

MessageClient client =  retrofit.create(MessageClient.class);
Call<List<Message>> call = client.getMessages();

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Message>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Message>> call, Response<List<Message>> response) {
        List<Message> messageList = response.body();
        Log.d(TAG, "LIST: "+messageList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, "API ERROR: "+t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

**Sample data from API**

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "details": "Message1.",
    "client_id": 1,

},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Title 2",
    "details": "Message 2.",
    "client_id": 1,
}]
```

Where am I missing it? Please note the API sample data.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: can you more clearly state the actual question?

Comment: Also, note that recent versions of Retrofit make it very easy to log the raw HTTP conversation.

Comment: I am getting this error **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

Comment: Please update the question with these details (Also, **where** are you seeing this error, and **when**?). Anyway, you are giving it an object, not an array. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36177629/1531971

Comment: But from the sample data I provided, the API is returning an array of objects so I cant seem to understand this error, please help and be patient I am a bit new to programming

Comment: You should try and understand the dup I found. It is almost certainly the same problem.

Comment: *cant seem to find a solution. I have Googled around but to no avail* what exactly are you googling? There are a million questions about this already, I don't believe you didn't find any of them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the API is not returning one message, it is returning an array of messages. So you need to map it as a list, not as a single message.

So I suggest that:
1. You create an additional model, bean or pojo.
You can call it `MessageList`, and it would look something like:

```
public class MessagesList {
  private List<Message> messageList;
//add getters and setters .. etc.
}
```

2. I think you should also change `List<Message>` in your code to `MessageList` instead.

This should allow the list of messages returned by the API to be mapped to the `MessageList` model, each individual message will be mapped to a `Message` object with it's (unique?) id, title and details. And you are able now to iterate through the list to get each `Message`.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. But I realized that the code is ok as it is, only that I was using a wrong API url.