# Realm createAllFromJson throws BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT exception

Tags: android, json, realm, retrofit, realm-migration

I'm developing an android mobile app and I was able to use retrofit to download a json file and kept it in the local storage (under download folder). However, when I use createAllFromJson to insert the contents of the json file into the reaml database, it throws the exception: BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36178202/758961) but with no luck.

Here is the code snippet:

JSON:

```
{
    "id": "2.1",
    "description": "Initial release",
    "version_external_id": "",
    "released": false,
    "source": {
        "created_on": "2018-01-08T13:02:37.017",
        "name": "Classification",
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "Item",
            "id": "1",
            "display_name": "TV",
            "descriptions": "Household item",
        },
        {
            "type": "Item",
            "id": "2",
            "display_name": "CD Player",
            "descriptions": "Household item",
        }
    ]
}
```

Models:

```
public class ItemList extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("items")
    private RealmList<Item> getItems;
}

public class Item extends RealmObject
{
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String display_name;
    private String descriptions;
//getter and setters...
}
```

Method to read json and insert data into realm database

```
private void populateItemList() {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"items.json");
                try {
                    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
                realm.createAllFromJson(ItemList.class, stream);

                }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if(realm.isInTransaction())
                        realm.cancelTransaction();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your JSON seems to be wrong. Can you try this once?

{
 "id": "2.1",
 "description": "Initial release",
 "version_external_id": "",
 "released": false,
 "source": {
  "created_on": "2018-01-08T13:02:37.017",
  "name": "Classification"
 },
 "items": [{
   "type": "Item",
   "id": "1",
   "display_name": "TV",
   "descriptions": "Household item"
  },
  {
   "type": "Item",
   "id": "2",
   "display_name": "CD Player",
   "descriptions": "Household item"
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `createAllFromJson` to `createObjectFromJson` and it is working now.