# REST API call always onFailure

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

I am new to Android rest api, basically I was trying to retrieve some information from a demo website using rest api together with the retrofit. Somehow my api call always on failure, hope someone could help.

Api.class

```
String BASE_URL = "https://demo.openmrs.org/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/";
@GET("location?tag=Login%20Location")
Call<List<RetroLocation>> getLocation();
```

Location.class

```
@SerializedName("display")
@Expose
protected String display;

@Expose
private String name;

 public RetroLocation() {}

public RetroLocation(String display) {
    this.display = display;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Call the api from the main class

```
private void retriveLocation() {
    //create object for the RetrofitInstance
    RestApi api = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RestApi.class);
    //making the call object using the api method created in the api class
    Call<List<RetroLocation>> call = api.getLocation();
    //making the call using enqueue(), it takes callback interface as an argument
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RetroLocation>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<RetroLocation>> call, Response<List<RetroLocation>> response) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
            if (response.body() != null) {
                //goes to my list
                List<RetroLocation> locationList = response.body();
                //creating an string array for the listview
                String[] location = new String[locationList.size()];
                //fill in the array with the response data from json
                for (int i = 0; i < locationList.size(); i++) {
                    location[i] = locationList.get(i).getName();
                }
                //displaying the string array into the listView
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_row, R.id.location, location);
                listviewLocation.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.d("result", "Respond");

                //generateDataList(response.body());
            }else
                Log.d("result", "No response");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<RetroLocation>> call, Throwable t) {
            //if(progressDoalog != null && progressDoalog.isShowing())
            //progressDoalog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("result", "onFailuer");

        }
    });
```

RestInstance.class

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RestApi.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
    if(retrofit!=null)
    Log.d("result", "logged in");

    return retrofit;
}

static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();
                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Basic "+ getAuth())
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .method(original.method(),original.body())
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        }).build();
```

Update: Here is the throwable error message

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

The output of base_url

```
   <org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.SimpleObject serialization="custom">
<unserializable-parents/>
<map>
<default>
<loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
<threshold>12</threshold>
</default>
<int>16</int>
<int>3</int>
<string>uuid</string>
<string>b1a8b05e-3542-4037-bbd3-998ee9c40574</string>
<string>display</string>
<string>Inpatient Ward</string>
<string>links</string>
<list>
<org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.web.Hyperlink>
<rel>self</rel>
<uri>
http://demo.openmrs.org/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/location/b1a8b05e-3542-4037-bbd3-998ee9c40574
</uri>
</org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.web.Hyperlink>
</list>
</map>
<linked-hash-map>
<default>
<accessOrder>false</accessOrder>
</default>
</linked-hash-map>
</org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.SimpleObject>
<org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.SimpleObject serialization="custom">
<unserializable-parents/>
<map>
<default>
<loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
<threshold>12</threshold>
</default>
<int>16</int>
<int>3</int>
<string>uuid</string>
<string>2131aff8-2e2a-480a-b7ab-4ac53250262b</string>
<string>display</string>
<string>Isolation Ward</string>
<string>links</string>
<list>
<org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.web.Hyperlink>
<rel>self</rel>
<uri>
http://demo.openmrs.org/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/location/2131aff8-2e2a-480a-b7ab-4ac53250262b
</uri>
</org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.web.Hyperlink>
</list>
</map>
<linked-hash-map>
<default>
<accessOrder>false</accessOrder>
</default>
</linked-hash-map>
</org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.SimpleObject>
```

Comment: onFailure is called with `Throwable `, Can you see what is error?

Comment: @Khemraj Sorry, but how can I view the error in Android Studio?

Comment: print the value of Throwable t into log. like Log.d("Failure Error", t.toString());

Comment: add `t.printStackTrace();` in `onFailure`

Comment: Can you show us your error log by printing error like above?

Comment: you have a BASE_URL but i don't see it being used anywhere! can you add your RetrofitInstance code to your question?

Comment: can you show a hit of your api on browser beacause from here its clear that your api require a `@Query` param of type `tag` which you are not supplying in the method getLocation()

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177629/retrofit2-android-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2)

Comment: since your code is expecting an array but your exception shows that the result is an object so try to parse json correctly

Comment: paste your result json..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

**BASE URL**  https://demo.openmrs.org/

**Retrofit Interface**

```
 @GET("openmrs/ws/rest/v1/location")
 Call<List<RetroLocation>> getLocation(@Query("tag") String tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like this may work.

```
String BASE_URL = "https://demo.openmrs.org/";
@GET("openmrs/ws/rest/v1/location?tag=Login%20Location")
Call<List<RetroLocation>> getLocation();
```